# OnCreateOptionsMenu with ActionBarSherlock library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fatal-error, oncreateoptionsmenu

I'm using ActionBarSherlock library in my app. I followed this [Tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/) but it is not working, app crashes as soon as it starts due to OnCreateOptionsMenu(). I can get what is the error. Please help

```
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097): Cannot instantiate class: com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:488)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:447)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:468)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:190)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.earth.map.location.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:71)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:44)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:64)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:164)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:397)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:759)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2992)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:264)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:252)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  ... 24 more
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  ... 32 more
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010030 a=-1}
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2053)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:803)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:477)
03-11 14:29:16.037: W/MenuInflater(10097):  ... 35 more
03-11 14:29:16.045: D/AndroidRuntime(10097): Shutting down VM
03-11 14:29:16.045: W/dalvikvm(10097): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418ab2a0)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.earth.map.location.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:76)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:44)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:64)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:164)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:397)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:759)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2992)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-11 14:29:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(10097):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
....
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Which line is `line#71` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` ?

Comment: inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

Comment: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { is line 68 and so on

Comment: I guess this is happening on Android 4+, right?

Comment: 03-11 14:57:15.701: E/AndroidRuntime(10486):  at com.earth.map.location.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:76)
And the line 76 is searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing which I noticed while ago when using `ActionBarSherlock` is that to use it correctly and without any errors, you should use one of the themes from this library as your parent in all folders (`values, values-v11, values-v14`). So I guess in your `values-v14/styles` or `values-v14/themes`, depends on where is your main custom theme which you are using for your application, instead of using `Theme.Holo` as your parent, change it to use one of the themes from `ActionBarSherlock` :

- Theme.Sherlock
- Theme.Sherlock.Light
- Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar
- Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar
- Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why your are using action bar sherlock? You can directly use actiobar activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: it should be a comment... and also it does not answer OP's question